# FB Graph API (Insights) Multiple Queries In One Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a graph API call:

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/atc_48485453349353/insights/?date_preset=last_14d&fields=account_name,campaign_name,adset_name&level=ad&breakdowns=age,gender&limit=99999999&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I get some data on an ad level. So this will return the maximum number of rows. However, since I'm operating at an ad level with `level=ad`. **There are certain fields that I don't have access to. For example the `date_start` and `date_stop` of the campaign and adset level. At the ad level, I can't access the adset budget either.**

I don't want to have to make 3 API calls. For all levels. **level=campaign, then level=adset, then level=ad**

Is there a way to form the request so I can do it all in one API call? (Including a way to get the adset budget in this request)